# Click DIV to open inline background in new tab

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically inserting a background-image in DIVs.

```
<div class="mc-image " title="The Bridges" style="background-image: url(image.jpg);" data-href="link.html"></div>
<div class="mc-image " title="The Bridges" style="background-image: url(image2.jpg);" data-href="link2.html"></div>
```

There could be up to 5 or 6 of these. On phone I want to open these background images in a new tab so people can view the whole image (zoom, pinch etc)

What is the jQuery I could use to do this?

Comment: why don't you just do link with image inside your div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way

```
jQuery('.mc-image').on('click', function() {
      var bg = jQuery(this).css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"]?/,'').replace(/['"]?\)$/,'');
      window.open(bg);
  });
```